# View the HTML-code instead of rendered HTML

Tags: html, linux

I remember that there exists a Linux command that returns the HTML-code from a given URL.
Instead of entering the URL in a browser you can give the URL as a parameter to this command and the HTML-code will be returned.

Which command does this?

Comment: If you just want to get the raw html, a simple call to ``wget`` should do the trick.

Comment: With which option can I get the raw HTML? wget <URL> saves the file but then I have to open the file to see the HTML. I now that it is possible to see the raw HTML directly but forgot the command.

Comment: SailorCire's answer below should do it.  (Add the ``-O -`` to your wget command.)

Answer (score 0):

wget is your friend

```
wget location -O -
```

This will dump it to stdout (i.e. your terminal)